# UIbutton no longer performing action when its rotated and moved

Tags: xcode, view, uibutton, location

I have a view which is rotated by the user's touch, the view has 4 button that move around relative to the view. if i then try to tap on one it doesn't respond,it still thinks the button is in its initial location. please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that there is nothing else **overlapping** the button as it would respond to the tap instead of the button does. In interface builder turn on **show bounding rectangles**